# Unable to link user to Whatsapp channel

Tags: smooch

I've configured my Whatsapp number to work with Smooch Sandbox. I've created an App and an user with an Free Trial account. However, I can't link my user to the Whatsapp channel. I've sent a request to https://api.smooch.io/v1/apps/appId/appusers/appUserId/channels with the following JSON body:

```
{"type": "whatsapp", "confirmation": {"type": "immediate"}, "phoneNumber": ""}
```

It returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "bad_request",
        "description": "Linking not supported for whatsapp sandbox integrations."
    }
}
```

How do I config my App to work with Smooch Sandbox for WhatsApp? The REST api docs are not updated with any Whatsapp specifications.

Comment: Do you have a need to specifically use the linking API? If you send a message to the WhatsApp Sandbox phone number (the same place you confirmed the sandbox integration), it will create an appUser automatically. See also the documentation for [user-initiated conversations](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/whatsapp/#user-initiated) on WhatsApp

Comment: I don't have a need to use the linking API. I've tried a lot of different ways to send messages but none of them worked. How do i get the Id of the automatically created appUser? I will try to send a message from that appUser.

Comment: If you go to the Logs tab of the Smooch web dashboard, you should see an event for the incoming message and the ID of the user